# PowershellScript: Incorrect Item count results for online Archive Office 365

Tags: powershell, office365, ms-office

I have created a script that exports into csv file the total item count in users online archive mailbox in office 365. However the results are incorrect. For purpose of testing, i manually archived three emails by dragging and drop in outlook on web, then run the `Start-ManagedFolderAssistant` for that mailbox. Next was to query the archive mailbox for that user and the total item count I get is only one. I was getting this one item count even when the archive mailbox is empty.

I don't know if have missed anything in the script.

Below is the script

```
$mails = get-mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -archive
$mails | foreach-object{

$mailbox = $_.UserPrincipalName
$username = $_.UserName
$archive = get-mailboxstatistics -Identity $mailbox -archive

New-object -typename PSobject -property @{

UserPrincipalName = $mailbox
UserName = $username
TotalItemCount = $archive.ItemCount

}

} | Export-CSV "c:\results5.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

I'm expecting the total item count to be three.